# Questions about derivable rules of inference

Tags: logic

As I understand, a derivable rule of inference is supposed to be eliminable and admissible (though eliminability implies admissiblity).

> **Definition:** Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a formal system. The rule
>   $$\frac{\Gamma}{C}$$
>   is a derivable rule in $\mathcal{S}$ iff $\Gamma \vdash_{\mathcal{S}} C$.

Source of the definition:

1. https://www.irif.fr/~roziere/admiss/mscs93.pdf See definition 1.2.1
2. http://www.few.vu.nl/~cgr600/linkedfiles/abstract_csl03.pdf See second line.

Other definitions:

1. $\Gamma \vdash_\mathcal{S} C$ means there is a proof of $C$ from $\Gamma$ *in* $\mathcal{S}$.
2. For definition of a proof I'm using the one on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof):

   > A formal proof or derivation is a finite sequence of sentences (called well-formed formulas in the case of a formal language), each of which is an axiom, an assumption, or follows from the preceding sentences in the sequence by a rule of inference.

Let's say $\mathcal{S}$ is classical propositional logic. And we want to add this derivable rule (actually a rule schema):

$$\frac{A \wedge \neg B}{\neg (A \to B)}$$

Now I can use the following derivation to satisfy the definition:

[image: Derivation]

Questions:

1. The formulas in the above derivation mix metavariables and symbols of the object language. The formal system only defines the notion of a derivation at the object language level (each line must be a wff of object language). How could it be used at the meta level to derive the rule schema (each line is not a wff of the object language as it contains metavariables)? Isn't this a problem with the above definition?
2. How would we show that this definition of a derivable rule satisfies the criteria of eliminability? I'm guessing we'd need a notion of transforming a derivation with derivable rules into a derivation with only primitive rules, and using it to prove the theorem:

   > Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a formal system and $\mathcal{S}^+$ be $\mathcal{S}$ augmented with derivable rules. Then $\Gamma \vdash_{\mathcal{S}^+} \phi$ implies $\Gamma \vdash_{\mathcal{S}} \phi$.

   How do I do this?

   Also this theorem is what shows eliminability implies admissibility.

Comment: "The formulas in the above derivation mix metavariables and symbols of the object language" Why ? You can express [ND rules](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) as schemas.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But schemas are supposed to be statements in the metalaguage, and their metavariables are supposed to be replaced with wffs from object language. In the case of the derivation above, the metavariables in the inference rules (used to justify proof steps) are replaced by other metavariables. No?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I added some more explanation to question 1 about what I mean.

Comment: The definition of *derivation* is obviously expressed in the meta-language: what else ? See e.g. [Chiswell & Hodges](https://www.ibisc.univ-evry.fr/~belardinelli/Documents/Logique/Mathematical-Logic-ChiswellHodges.pdf) page 7 : a *sequent* is an expression $(Γ \vdash  ψ)$, and so on...

Comment: An *inference rule* is expressed in the meta-language: it is an "instruction" how to manage formulas (i.e. expressions of the object language). We can easily express them using only natural language: "In a derivation whatever, from every a pair of formulas occurring into the derivation we can derive a new formula written with the first formula followed by the simbol for conjunction followed by the second formula". It is quite natural the benefits of using meta-variables (schematic letters).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok I'll accept that the same inference rule can be used in object language level derivations and metalanguage level derivations, and that axioms can also be used in this way. Still, a derivation at the meta level is different from one at object level. The derivation above is at the meta level. All definitions of derivable rules I have seen require a derivation in $\mathcal{S}$ though.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a specific reference for the definitions of derivability etc. that are causing you problems. Your point about metavariables v. object variables isn't really relevant in a logic whose inference system is closed under substitution for the free variables in a proof. The definition of derivability that you give apparently assumes this closure property, but it's hard to say more  unless you give more context.

Comment: @RobArthan No problem. I added two sources below the definition. Also could you explain what this means: "inference system is closed under substitution for the free variables in a proof". If it would take too long, could you tell where I can read about it? Thanks.

Comment: @RobArthan Sorry the sources are not books, so may not give context. Thing is, books at my level don't even seem to talk about it. For example Language, Proof and Logic by Barwise et al. It's one of the things that makes logic so hard: there's so much unwritten stuff that you keep tripping over if you dare to look deeper than what you're told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to self: The "rule" here is defined as only composed of WFFs of $\mathcal{S}$. Am I right here?

1. Technically, the theorem you proved using the derivation in the question is:

   > All rules of *the form*
   >   $$\frac{A \wedge \neg B}{\neg (A \to B)}$$
   >   (where $A,B$ are any WFF in $\mathcal{S}$) are derivable in $\mathcal{S}$.

The derivation in the question then serves as the "template proof" for the derivability of all instances of the rule schema; substitute any WFF on all meta-variables in that proof, and you get a formal derivation (as defined) of a rule.

Regarding Rob Arthan's comment on "metavariables v. object variables isn't really relevant...", you can work with propositional logic/s without any rule schema EXCEPT the substitution rule schema $\frac{A}{A[p\mapsto B]}$ where $A,B$ are any WFF, $p$ is an atomic proposition, and $A[p\mapsto B]$ means "The WFF after replacing every $p$ in $A$ by $B$." This means that atomic propositions themselves can be replaced by any WFF. This rule schema makes meta-variables and object variables(atomic propositions) "the same".

2. **EDIT:** Your idea of "transforming" the derivation is correct. Just look on the definition of proof: that it is a **finite sequence** of WFFs. When the proof of $\Gamma \vdash_{\mathcal{S}^+} \phi$ requires derivable rules, for all lines of proof wherein any derivable rule is used, insert between the premises WFFs and the conclusion WFF, the "middle" lines (i.e. the lines that are not the premises and the conclusion) of the proof of derivability of that derivable rule.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your question: "The "rule" here is defined as only composed of WFFs of $\mathcal{S}$. Am I right here?" Yes that is what I meant. Regarding question 2, I understand it intuitively, I just needed help defining the notion of eliminability and showing derivable rules (as defined) are eliminable.

Comment: continued... I was thinking for eliminability, we'd define it as: Any sequent provable in the augmented formal system is also provable in the primitive formal system.

Comment: continued... To show a derivable rule is eliminable then, we would have to show in any proof step where it is used, that line can be replaced with a derivation using only primitive rules. This last step is where I'm having issues.

Comment: I edited my answer (for question 2). The meanings of "rule" and "proof" still apply.